# Lightswitch Application.ShowScreen - how to refer screen I move to?

Tags: visual-studio-lightswitch

I have 2 screens, one is a list, other is a detail with parameter filtering from Id on first screen. When I made filter on detail screen, and put parameter, Application.ShowDetail remain args free. I found only way to send params through ShowScreen, but dont get how to select screen for it. It needed IScreenDefinition.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a *screen property* to a screen (using *Add Data Item*) that you want to have used as a parameter for the screen, you have to make sure that you tick *Is Parameter* in the properties pane for the screen property.